# How to get spinner control selected id

Tags: android

I've a spinner control that I connected it via a dataadapter and I get the data through it .

in the class, I want to get the selected spinner control's id . 
How can I do that ?

I've used this code but when I run it , it says there's a problem and it closed .

```
Toast toast=Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,sp.getSelectedItemId(),5000);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,100, 0);
toast.show();
```

I tried getSelectedItemId and getSelectedItemPosition  but non of them worked .

Comment: Is that time duration `5000` working for you? I mean, `Toast.LENGTH_LONG` and `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` are the only two values that can be used there, as far as I've read.

Answer (score 0):

Here the answer for your question

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, strType);
adpt.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spnType.setAdapter(adpt);
spnType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
 {
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3)
  {
    int intItemType = spnType.getSelectedItemPosition();
  }
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) 
  {

  }
});
```

This the line getting selected position of the spinner

```
    int intItemType = spnType.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try this

            //Spinner OnItemClick Event here
            payfeeTabStudentNameSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {

                String spinnerSelectedValue = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                }
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });

Please let me know your problem is resolved or not.
```